# Load a thumbnail with glide while also getting a bitmap

Tags: android, imageview, android-bitmap, android-glide

I have an ImageView where I have to load a large image. I have available a low-res of said image that I would like to load as a preview before the full-quality image finishes downlaoding and appears on screen.

With this method:

```
private void loadImageThumbnailRequest() {
    // setup Glide request without the into() method
    DrawableRequestBuilder<String> thumbnailRequest = Glide
            .with( context )
            .load( eatFoodyImages[2] );

    // pass the request as a a parameter to the thumbnail request
    Glide
            .with( context )
            .load( UsageExampleGifAndVideos.gifUrl )
            .thumbnail( thumbnailRequest )
            .into( imageView3 );
}
```

I can achieve my result, but I cannot obtain the bitmap of the downloaded image, since I can't use both `.asBitmap` and `.thumbnail` and `SimpleTarget` in the same Glide instance.

My actual code:

```
.asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL) {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation glideAnimation) {
                    mWallpaperImageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    createPaletteAsync(resource);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Glide 4, just create a listener to obtain it in the end:

```html
.listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        //do what you want with resource;
                        return false;
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

`.into` won't work to preload a `Bitmap`. Indeed `.preload` will. @Amit's answer is not very accurate if you don't add `preload()`. See my example:

```
        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(imageUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.3f)
                .listener(object: RequestListener<Bitmap> {
                    override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Bitmap>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        System.out.println("here's your exception")
                        return true
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap?, model: Any?, target: Target<Bitmap>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                        System.out.println("here's your bitmap")
                        return true
                    }

                })
                .preload()
```